# Major product in the reaction of alcohol with unsymmetrical acid anhydride

Tags: organic-chemistry, alcohols, esters, carboxylic-acids

When alcohol reacts with symmetrical acid anhydride to form ester. We have the following reaction,
[image]
But if the acid anhydride used is unsymmetrical how can we identify the major product? For example in the following reaction which is ester is the major product?
[image]
I tried searching the internet for the mechanism of this reaction but was able to find none. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: My feeling is that it will be determined by which R group confers more hindrance to the carbonyl group. If there isn't much difference then you will get close to a 1:1 mixture

Comment: @Waylander Do you know which bond of the alcohol will break, C-O or O-H? Is it similar to the reaction of alcohols with carboxylic acid?

Comment: O-H will break. It is similar to the reaction of an alcohol with an acyl chloride or activated ester. The other product is the carboxylic acid